# Usage of 目黒 outside of 目黒区

Tags: meaning, usage, names, word-usage

I am wondering if 目黒 can be used as a noun outside of its usage as a district name.

Examining each character,

- 目 eye, vision, sight, etc.
- 黒 black, guilt, etc.

provides a couple of interesting interpretations:

- black eye
- vision of guilt

Is it possible to interpret 目黒 in such ways, or is it simply a district name that holds no other meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions like these are usually best resolved by looking in a (monolingual) dictionary (and/or on a Wikipedia disambiguation page).

For example, [大辞林 has two entries for 目黒](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%9B%AE%E9%BB%92-643651#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88):

> **めぐろ**【目黒】
>
> ① スズメ目ミツスイ科の小鳥。スズメ大で背面は暗緑色、腹面は黄色で、目の周囲に黒い三角斑がある。森林にすみ、花蜜を吸ったり昆虫を食べる。小笠原諸島特産。特別天然記念物。オガサワラメジロ。
>
> ② 鮪{まぐろ}の小さいもの。めじか。 「 －のせんば煮／浮世草子・五人女 1」
>
> ---
>
> **めぐろ**【目黒】
>
> 東京都二三区の一。二三区の南西部にある。住宅・商業地区。

While the second entry is about the Tokyo district *Meguro*, the first entry lists two meanings — one being a particular bird species, a [bonin white-eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonin_white-eye), the other being a name for a small tuna.

[大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%9B%AE%E9%BB%92-643651#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) lists yet another meaning, namely that 目黒 can be used as a different name for "pupil", which is usually 黒目 *kurome*.

The etymologies of マグロ "tuna" (=目黒【まぐろ】?) or the district *Meguro* are not 100% clear, but in the other cases it is quite clear that it is used for the literal meanings of "eye" and "black".

Using 目黒 with other meanings (such as "guilty vision") which are not listed in a reasonably complete dictionary will most likely just result in confusion.

Comment: なるほど。In the future, I'll do more research before posting a question.  ありがとうございます。